# I made a EFI-bootable FAT32 USB drive, then formated the main part as NTFS as a loaner to a relative, and now their Surface won't see it

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, ntfs

Now all I get is what's pictured below. The weirdest part is that it all showed up just fine on their desktop Windows computer when we were copying files to it; it's just their Surface that can't see it.

There's important data on there, so I don't want to reformat or anything. Also, **it's with a remote family member** so I have to be able to give them simple instructions for how to get the data off.

An ideal solution would probably involve making a disk image of just that partition, but I'm wary about what to try since I will have to "try" it by telling my relative to do this via instant messages, and one wrong move might erase the data entirely.

**What's the simplest way to get the data out of the below-shown 28.56GB partition?**

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: ARM based Surface runs Windows RT which may explain the differences. It should support NTFS but may not in a multi partition USB stick. There no point in keeping that EFI partiton either. Perhaps better to use a cloud service (Mega is free up to 50GB) and then later troubleshoot *in situ* when you have the opportunity.

Comment: Windows handles "removable" media with multiple partitions strangely. If its two partitions with an ESP it always mounts the first and ignores the rest. With an ESP I've gotten extremely weird behavior like Explore reporting stats from the second partition while opening files from the ESP. This is a known bug so @MichaelBay you've pretty much given the answer.

Comment: Oh, I should've said... It's a Surface 4, so x86_64, not ARM

Comment: I ended up zipping up the files and sending them over... but I'd still love to know what happened here and how to fix it in the future